# Managing constructors with many parameters in Java

Tags: java

In some of our projects, there's an class hierarchy that adds more parameters as it goes down the chain. At the bottom, some of the classes can have up to 30 parameters, 28 of which are just being passed into the super constructor.

I'll acknowledge that using automated DI through something like Guice would be nice, but because of some technical reasons, these specific projects are constrained to Java.

A convention of organizing the arguments alphabetically by type doesn't work because if a type is refactored (the Circle you were passing in for argument 2 is now a Shape) it can suddenly be out of order.

This question might be to specific and fraught with "If that's your problem, you're doing it wrong at a design level" criticisms, but I'm just looking for any viewpoints.

Answer (score 330, accepted):

The Builder Design Pattern might help.  Consider the following example

```
public class StudentBuilder
{
    private String _name;
    private int _age = 14;      // this has a default
    private String _motto = ""; // most students don't have one

    public StudentBuilder() { }

    public Student buildStudent()
    {
        return new Student(_name, _age, _motto);
    }

    public StudentBuilder name(String _name)
    {
        this._name = _name;
        return this;
    }

    public StudentBuilder age(int _age)
    {
        this._age = _age;
        return this;
    }

    public StudentBuilder motto(String _motto)
    {
        this._motto = _motto;
        return this;
    }
}
```

This lets us write code like

```
Student s1 = new StudentBuilder().name("Eli").buildStudent();
Student s2 = new StudentBuilder()
                 .name("Spicoli")
                 .age(16)
                 .motto("Aloha, Mr Hand")
                 .buildStudent();
```

If we leave off a required field (presumably name is required) then we can have the Student constructor throw an exception.
And it lets us have default/optional arguments without needing to keep track of any kind of argument order, since any order of those calls will work equally well.

Comment: Of course with static imports you never even have to "see" these "builders" at all. For example, you could have static methods name(String name) which returns a builder and Student(StudentBuilder) which returns a student. Hence Student(name("Joe").age(15).motto("I've wet myself"));

Comment: @oxbow_lakes: In your example, which class has static method name(String name)?

Comment: Technically speaking, it is possible to use Student class to build a new student. I've added the methods inside the Student class and it worked just fine. This way I didn't need to have another builder class. I'm not sure if this is desirable though. Is there a reason to use another(StudentBuilder) class to build it?

Comment: @WVrock: It depends on your implementation.  As I say in my answer, doing this with the student class itself could potentially leave the class in a half-initialized state, e.g. if you have a required field which has not yet been initialized.

Comment: @EliCourtwright I guess it is about preference/code design. Instead of making the constructor throw the exception I made the `buildStudent()` method throw the exception.

Comment: I would say, this is a nice solution

Answer (score 29):

Can you encapsulate related parameters inside an object?

e.g., if parameters are like

```
MyClass(String house, String street, String town, String postcode, String country, int foo, double bar) {
  super(String house, String street, String town, String postcode, String country);
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = bar;
```

then you could instead have:

```
MyClass(Address homeAddress, int foo, double bar) {
  super(homeAddress);
  this.foo = foo;
  this.bar = bar;
}
```

Answer (score 14):

What you probably want to do is have a Builder class. Then you would do something like this:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObjectBuilder().setXxx(myXxx)
                                    .setYyy(myYyy)
                                    .setZzz(myZzz)
                                    // ... etc.
                                    .build();
```

See page 8 and following of [this Josh Bloch presentation](http://docs.huihoo.com/javaone/2007/java-se/TS-2689.pdf) (PDF), or [this review of Effective Java](http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue163.html)

Answer (score 12):

Well, using the builder pattern might be *one* solution.

But once you come to 20 to 30 parameters, I would guess that there is a high relationship between the parameters. So (as suggested) wrapping them into logically sane data-objects probably makes the most sense. This way the data object can already check the validity of constraints between the parameters.

For all of my projects in the past, once I came to the point to have too many parameters (and that was 8 not 28!) I was able to sanitize the code by creating a better datamodel.

Answer (score 4):

The best solution is not having too much parameters in the constructor. Only parameters really needed in constructor, are params that are need to correctly initialize the object. You can have constructors with multiple parameters, but also have a constructor with only the minimum parameters. The additional constructors call this simple constructor and after that setters to set the other params. This way you can avoid the chain-problem with more and more params, but also have some convenience-constructors.

Answer (score 4):

As you are constrained to Java 1.4, if you want DI then [Spring](http://www.springframework.org) would be a very decent option. DI is only helpful in places where the constructor parameters are services or something that does not vary during runtime.

If you have all of those different constructors due to the fact that you want variable options on how to construct an object, you should seriously consider using the Builder pattern.

Comment: The parameters are mostly services as you mentioned, and so DI is what I'd be needing. I think the Builder pattern mentioned in a couple other answers is exactly what I was hoping for.

Answer (score 3):

I can really recommend using [Immutables](http://immutables.github.io) or [POJOBuilder](https://github.com/mkarneim/pojobuilder) when using the builder pattern.

Comment: That's a great reference. I think `Lombok` does both.

Answer (score 2):

Refactoring to reduce the number of parameters and depth of you inheritance hierarchy is pretty much all I can think of because, nothing is really going to help keep 20-something parameters straight.  You're just going to have to every single call while looking at the documentation.

One thing you could do, is to group some logically grouped parameters into their own higher level object, but that has it's own problems.