# Java Error - Actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: java

I am trying to call a method, but it is giving this error:

> **java:112: error:** 
>   **required:** String, String
>
> **found:** String
>
> **reason:** actual and formal arguments lists differ in length

Here is the method I'm trying to call:

```
public void setShippingDest(String inCustName, String inDestn) {
    // ...
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to call it:

```
shipOrder.setShippingDest("Broome");
```

Comment: I'd also have a look at using a unit testing framework, such as [junit](http://junit.org/) or [testng](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) for writing your tests, so that you have much more manageable testing than what you have with your humongous `main()` method approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well it's quite simple. Here's the declaration of `setShippingDest`:

```
public void setShippingDest(String inCustName, String inDestn)
```

And here's how you're trying to call it:

```
shipOrder.setShippingDest("Broome");
```

You've provided one argument, but there are two parameters? How do you expect that to work? You either need to provide another argument, or remove one parameter.

(I'd also strongly advise that you remove the `in` prefix from all of your parameters, and look into a real unit testing framework such as JUnit, rather than writing an enormous `main` method.)

Comment: @Ammu: It's worth taking a step back and working out why you couldn't figure it out from the compiler error message. Did you not know where to look? Did you not understand the message? Basically, try to learn from this experience so you can fix it yourself next time.

Answer (score 1):

Also if you like to specify only the Customer Name, you could do so by overloading the method as

```
    public void setShippingDest(String inCustName)
    {
      return  setShippingDest(inCustName, defaultvalue1);
    }
```

See [how to set default method argument values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1038383/how-to-set-default-method-argument-values)