# How to include a print statement from another method inside the class

Tags: java

My question is how do I change my code so that it prints out my first print line along with the lines printed from the `testBuildCodonMap` method? The print line that currently doesn't print out is `System.out.println(s+"\t"+codonMap.get(s));`. I want this to be included with the other print statements.

```
import java.util.*;
import edu.duke.*;

public class CodonCount {
    private HashMap<String,Integer> codonMap;
    public CodonCount() {
        codonMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    }
    private void buildCodonMap(int start, String dna) {
        //clear out map before building
        codonMap.clear();
        //This method will build a new map of codons mapped to 
        //their counts from the string dna with the reading frame
        //with the position start (a value of 0, 1, or 2).
        for (int index=start; dna.length() - index > 3;index+=3) {
            String currentCodon = dna.substring(index,index+3);
            if (!codonMap.containsKey(currentCodon)) {
                codonMap.put(currentCodon,1);
            }
            else {
                codonMap.put(currentCodon,codonMap.get(currentCodon)+1);
            }
        }
    }
    private String getMostCommonCodon() {
        //get the codon in a reading frame that has the largest count
        //this method assumes the HashMap of codons to counts has already been built
        int currentHigh = 0;
        String mostCommonCodon = "";
        for (String s : codonMap.keySet()) {
            int currentCount = codonMap.get(s);
            if (currentCount > currentHigh) {
                mostCommonCodon = s;
                currentHigh = currentCount;
            }
        }
        return mostCommonCodon;
    }
    private void printCodonCounts(int start, int end) {
        //This method prints all the codons in the HashMap along with their
        //counts if their count is between start and end, inclusive.
        for (String s : codonMap.keySet()) {
            if (codonMap.get(s) >= start && codonMap.get(s) <= end) {
                System.out.println(s+"\t"+codonMap.get(s));
            }
        }
    }
    public void testBuildCodonMap() {
        FileResource fileResource = new FileResource();
        String dna = fileResource.asString();
        dna = dna.toUpperCase();

        for (int index=0;index <= 2;index++) {
            System.out.println("\nTesting with start position "+index+":\n");
            buildCodonMap(index,dna);
            String mostCommonCodon = getMostCommonCodon();
            System.out.println("Total unique codons found: "+codonMap.size());
            System.out.println("\nMost common codon: "+mostCommonCodon
                                +"\t"+codonMap.get(mostCommonCodon));
            printCodonCounts(4,8);
        }
    }
}
```

**Sample file for testing:** `CGTTCAAGTTCAA`

**EDIT:** I want the output to look something like this:

Reading frame starting with 0 results in 3 unique codons

and most common codon is TCA with count 2

Counts of codons between 1 and 5 inclusive are:

CGT 1

TCA 2

AGT 1

Reading frame starting with 1 results in 2 unique codons

and most common codon is CAA with count 2

Counts of codons between 1 and 5 inclusive are:

CAA 2

GTT 2

Reading frame starting with 2 results in 2 unique codons

and most common codon is TTC with count 2

Counts of codons between 1 and 5 inclusive are:

TTC 2

AAG 1

Comment: Did you run over the code with a debugger to see why it doesn't print?

Comment: After your edit I suggest you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @user1803551 I did, and CTG came up as one of the codons being calculated. But I found nothing else.

Comment: Edited question to include MCVE.

Comment: Are you calling `printCodonCounts` anywhere else in your code? The error does state that you're calling it somewhere, and that it requires two ints, and somewhere you called it as `printCodonCounts()`. You have shown you have called it once in the provided code, and it was done correctly.

Comment: That's not an MCVE, we can't copy-paste your code and run it in our IDEs to see the problem.

Comment: Are you sure? I've included all of the code. Is there something missing I'm not seeing?

Comment: Show your `main()` method in a separate code block please.

Comment: It's missing a `main` and `FileResource` in undefined. I suggest you supply a sample input.

Comment: I'm using BlueJ so we don't have to use a `main()` method. I think the `main()` would be `testBuildCodonMap()` in another IDE.

Comment: Well the code provided wouldn't cause this exception. Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813484/java-error-actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ-in-length). This is what causes the problem you're having.

Comment: I tested your code, it throws no error. I get this output: `Testing with start position 0:

Total unique codons found: 3

Most common codon: TCA 2

Testing with start position 1:

Total unique codons found: 2

Most common codon: GTT 2

Testing with start position 2:

Total unique codons found: 2

Most common codon: TTC 2`

Comment: Yes, that's true. But I wanted the line inside `private void printCodonCounts(int start, int end)` to be included. It doesn't seem to be printing out.

Comment: if you debug it you will see that the `if` condition is never `true`, so of course it won't print anything. Besides, is your question about some error or about printing?

Comment: It is more about printing the right output. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The output you posted is nothing like the prints you have in your code. I suggest you formulate a clear question with information relevant to the code you posted and add an explanation *after using a debugger* of what you need help with.

Answer (score 1):

I got it! The line `printCodonCounts(4,8);` inside of the `public void testBuildCodonMap()` method needs to be changed to be `printCodonCounts(1,3);`.
That allows the print statement inside of method `private void printCodonCounts(int start, int end)` to execute.