# How to fix "Build Failure"/The first two problems of calculate premium on Cengage-Exercise-9

Tags: java

I'm just learning the creating method part of java, and because of that I have no idea of what it's even saying or asking from me when it says "Build Failure". I seemed to have completed the code just fine and the calculate premium does work and counts 2/4 of the answers right, but it seems no matter what I do it just always says "Build Failure" for the other 2 questions.

```
// Insurance.java
// Chapter 3, Exercise 9
import java.util.Scanner;
class Insurance{
   public static void main(String args[]){
      int currY, birthY, ageD = 0;

      Scanner scanny = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("What year was you born?");
      birthY = scanny.nextInt();
      System.out.println("What is the current year?");
      currY = scanny.nextInt();
      calculatePremium(currY, birthY, ageD);
   }
   public static void calculatePremium(int currY, int birthY, int ageD){
       ageD = (((birthY - currY)/10)+15)*20;
       System.out.println(ageD);
   }
}
```

I've tried changing the birthY and currY opposite, changing calculatePremium to an int, because I think it had int sign before it as kind of the setting up the answer, so it's easier on the student, and I put a void sign in place of the int, because I knew it would return the variable automatically.

Now this is the part I have no idea what it means since i'm still fairly new. The only part I can kind of understand is that 2016 - 1991 == 340, because the code wants to get the decades of your age, then + it by 15 then * by 20. I'm also having the problem of if i switch the `System.out.prinln` of the string code above it will say I got a question wrong, when that shouldn't even matter which order it's in.
Unit TestIncomplete
calculatePremium works for a 26 year old

Build Status

Build Failed

Build Output

```
NtTest4231c145.java:9: error: method calculatePremium in class Insurance cannot be applied to given types;
    assertTrue(tester47.calculatePremium(2016, 1991) == 340);
                       ^
  required: int,int,int
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
1 error
```

Test Contents

```
Insurance tester47 = new Insurance();

@Test
public void unitTest() {
    assertTrue(tester47.calculatePremium(2016, 1991) == 340);
}
```

The expected and actual results are the "Build Output" and the "Test Contents".

Comment: Probably duplicate: [actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22813484/java-error-actual-and-formal-argument-lists-differ-in-length)

Comment: The `calculatePremium` method expects *three* arguments (`int currY, int birthY, int ageD`), but the test code only provides *two* in `tester47.calculatePremium(2016, 1991)`, so you have a build error, i.e. the compiler cannot build the code.

Comment: Thank you, this stuff makes English sound like it's in a different language(no pun intended).