# private void function(Integer[] a, String str = "") like in PHP

Tags: java, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values)

Is it possible to do something like this

```
private void function(Integer[] a, String str = "")
```

like in PHP. If I don't provide str, it will just be empty. In PHP it's possible, in JAVA it gives me error. Or the only solution here is to create two methods like this?

```
private void function(Integer[] a, String str)
private void function(Integer[] a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exacly, there is no other option than:

```
private void function(Integer[] a, String str) {
    // ...
}

private void function(Integer[] a) {
    function(a, "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare your method with `var agrs`

`private void function(Integer[] a, String... s)`

Remember, var args should always be the last argument of the method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll have to use the second method.

```
private void function(Integer[] a, String str)
private void function(Integer[] a)
```

Answer (score 0):

That is indeed the only way to achieve such a thing, short of using a [**variable length method argument list**](http://www.deitel.com/articles/java_tutorials/20060106/VariableLengthArgumentLists.html).

**Example:**

```
private void function(Integer[] a, String... str) {

  for( String s : str )
  {
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this post:

[Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values)

Java does not handle this feature.