# Is it possible to create a method with variable number of input values?

Tags: java, methods

I want to create a method along the lines of `[return] methodName(int numberOfTimes, String[numberOfTimes] strings)`, meaning that, depending on the value of `numberOfChoices`, I can add that number of `String` values to the method.

I've wondered and, as I wrote it, it wouldn't work because it would fail at compile time, because `numberOfChoices` isn't defined, and, if it would compile, it'd still be tricky to work it out.

I think my best bet is going with `String... strings` and do a for loop like this:

```
void methodName(int numberOfTimes, String... strings) {
    for(int i = 0, i < numberOfTimes; i++) {
        // do something with strings[i]
    }
}
```

But I still wonder if what I originally wanted was possible.

EDIT: I'm dumb and am always thinking on "sharing" my methods outside of the workspace, that's why I want it to work on the most general way possible. Solution is actually removing `numberOfChoices` and just introducing as many `String` objects as needed in `methodName`. Something along the lines of `methodname("One", "Two")`. So, fixed code would be...

```
void methodName(String... choices) {
    for(int i = 0; i < choices.length; i++) {
        // do something with choices[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the rational of having the first parameter, apart from maybe validation? You could always just pass in as many arguments as you actually need.

Comment: `numberOfTimes` does seem redundant indeed...

Comment: You might want to look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values

Comment: Because I was thinking on doing a method that prints a menu-like text interface with a set number of choices and paired Strings, then return the choice selected as an int for it to be passed in a switch case statement.

EDIT: Actually, rethinking, it is indeed redundant, as I could just use the length of the array as limiter...

Answer (score 0):

if the variable parameter is always of the same type (like strings) you could use an array or list as a parameter, the method won't care what the size of the array is, just that it's an array

```
void methodName(int numberOfTimes, String[] myStrings)
```

Comment: you could also set the array as `Object[] array` so you can pass not only Strings

Comment: right, or use an ArrayList or whatever. just make sure you have exception handling in there for type mismatches

Answer (score 0):

The three periods after the final parameter's type indicate that the final argument may be passed as an array or as a sequence of String arguments. You could then use loop without knowing the number like:

```
for (String stringParam: args) {
   // your logic on stringParam
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java arrays are dynamic so their is no need to specify index within method argument

[return] methodname(int numberOfTimes, String[] strings)
it works

Comment: This is in fact the exact same as `methodname(int numberOfTimes, String ... strings)` - except that you have to put in an empty array or null if you do not want to pass any string to methodname.

Answer (score 0):

Java treats variable arguments as arrays, so you can iterate over `strings` like normal.

Example (returning all the strings concatenated with spaces):

```
public void wordsToSentence(String... words) {
    final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    boolean notFirst = false;
    for (String s : words) {
        if (notFirst) builder.append(" ");
        else notFirst = true;
        builder.append(s);
    }
    return builder.toString();
}
```