# Is it possible to declare default argument in Java in String?

Tags: java, methods, default-value

Is it possible to use default argument in the method with String. The code is shown below:

```
public void test(String name="exampleText") {
}
```

The code above generate error. Is it possible to correct it?

Comment: No that is not possible in Java.

Comment: This is usually solved with method overloading.

Comment: What you want to achieve?

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47441378/4217744

Answer (score 62, accepted):

No, the way you would normally do this is overload the method like so:

```
public void test()
{
    test("exampleText");
}

public void test(String name)
{

}
```

Answer (score 16):

No, it is not. However, the following is possible:

```
public void test() {
    test("exampleText");
}
public void test(String name) {
    //logic here
}
```