# Adding a parameter to a method that's used called from 100 different places in my project - What's the proper approach?

Tags: java, design-patterns

So I'm working on a codebase, and there's a utility class that deals with generating excel documents for users.

It has a method called `putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data)`

It has quite a few methods like `putObjectsIntoExcel(myBigClass blah)` and  `putObjectsIntoSpecialExcelType(myBigClass blah)`

which calls a load of methods like `putObjectIntoSpecialRowType(blah.foo(), rowIndex, specialConditions)` and `putObjectIntoTotallydifferentRowType(blah.bar(), rowIndex, specialConditions)`

The point of all this is that the method `putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data)` gets called a metric buttload, from a bunch of different places. like 100+.

Now, given this legacy code, I needed to modify the method to take additional parameters - styling information. 99% of the methods will now take 'null' as a fourth argument, and 1% will receive an object which contains styling information.

I modified the method signature, to receive the additional parameter, but I found myself having to write a regex to find/replace all of the method calls. it worked, but this felt like the wrong way to go about this.

How should I have done it?

Comment: What about using automatic refactoring tools ? `Change Method Signature...`

Comment: @Paul, do you consider your question answered? If so, please consider accepting one of the answers or otherwise elaborate on the question so the answers can be improved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let the old `putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data)` live on, and let it delegate its calls to `putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null)`.

```
public static Something putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, Whatever data){
    return putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null);
}
```

You could also have used a modern IDE to refactor the method with "add parameter" and provide a sensible default value for the new parameter, `null` in your case. :)

On that note, I also think you should avoid `null` as a "no styling" value, because it makes very little sense when you see code like `putDataInRowColumn(0, 5, data, null)` - isn't `putDataInRowColumn(0, 5, data, Styling.NONE)` a whole lot easier to read?

Comment: Just for orientation, the refactoring would be under "Change signature".

Answer (score 6):

You create a new overloaded method that accepts a fourth argument and let the old method call the new method with `null` as fourth argument.

**Before:**

```
public void putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, int data) {
    // implementation
}
```

**After:**

```
// 99% calls this
public void putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, int data) {
    // Delegates to new method with null as "default" argument
    putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null);
}

// Called by new code
public void putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, int data, Style style) {
    // implementation
}
```

---

**Related:**

- [Is it possible to declare default argument in Java in String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093327/is-it-possible-to-declare-default-argument-in-java-in-string)
- [Default argument values in Java](http://java.dzone.com/news/default-argument-values-java)

Answer (score 2):

write another overload method putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, additional) in the same class, and 99% of classes calls putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data) while change 1% of classes to call this new method.

```
//edit old method to call newer one.
putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data) 
{
putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to overload the method.

The new method sign would be:

`putDataInRowColumn(SomeType row, SomeType column, SomeType data, SomeType style)`

In this method you will check style parameter.

Then putDataInRowColumn(SomeType row, SomeType column, SomeType data) implementation will be:

`putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data) {
    putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null);
}`

If you follow this you don't have to do a refactor of previous code.

Answer (score 1):

If 99% of the calls don't need the 4th argument, it would make more sense to use method overloading, so that 99% of the calls remain unchanged.

For example (I made some arbitrary assumptions on the types of the arguments and the return type) :

Existing method :

```
putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, SomeType data) {
    putDataInRowColumn(row, column, data, null);
}
```

New method :

```
putDataInRowColumn(int row, int column, SomeType data, SomeOtherType) {
    the actual logic
}
```