# calling `this` from overloaded constructor

Tags: java

I've stumbled upon the following code:

```
public class PluginResult {

    public PluginResult(Status status) {
        this(status, PluginResult.StatusMessages[status.ordinal()]); //this line
    }

    public PluginResult(Status status, String message) {
        this.status = status.ordinal();
        this.messageType = message == null ? MESSAGE_TYPE_NULL : MESSAGE_TYPE_STRING;
        this.strMessage = message;
    }
```

I'm wondering what it does on this line:

```
this(status, PluginResult.StatusMessages[status.ordinal()]);
```

Is it calling another overloaded constructor of the same class?

Comment: It will call the constructor with two parameters.

Comment: Yes it's calling the constructor with two parameters which as a `Status` as first parameter and the return type of  `PluginResult.StatusMessages[status.ordinal()]` as second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, exactly. It's essentially the same (from the result standpoint) as providing default values of arguments in C++.

Comment: Didn't quite understand your analogy to C++ default values of arguments, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Maximus: Sure. In C++ you could've said something like: `public: PluginResult(Status status, string message = PluginResult.StatusMessages[status.ordinal()])` where `=` means "use the following for this parameter if none provided explicitly". Thus you effectively take care of both situations (when constructor is called with 1 argument and when constructor is called with 2 arguments) in 1 constructor definition. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Maximus: Not directly, but there are other ways to achieve relatively the same - please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this simply calls another constructor. This is quite common in Java, and you may call it "constructor delegation".

There are actually two kinds of delegation, `this` (which calls a constructor of the current class) and `super` (which calls a constructor of the superclass). They are mutually exclusive, and must appear as the *first* statement of a constructor.

Comment: This approach is needed, as I understand, because I can't specify default value of `PluginResult.StatusMessages[status.ordinal()]` for one of constructors, correct?

Comment: That's correct: you can't provide default arguments in Java.

Comment: Yep, it's clear now. Thanks. I've accepted _striving_coder_'s answer since he has less reputation, hope you don't mind :)