# Java alternative for C# code

Tags: java, c#

I have a function with the following declaration in c#. It allows me call the function without providing a value for the `expectedDisplayValue` variable. The function automatically initializes the variable to `""`. I want a similar declaration in java. How can I do that?

```
public bool VerifyControlState(string identifier,string controltype, ButtonProperty buttonProperty, string expectedDisplayValue = "");
```

Comment: You can't do that in Java, but see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values) for alternatives.

Comment: Dear java is not a mouth feeder like c#...
But you can achieve the above scenario with the help of function overloading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The structure of Java handles this through function overloading. Basically, create a function that doesn't have `expectedDisplayValue` as a parameter and that function would call `VerifyControlState (identifier, controltype, buttonProperty, "");`

See the [Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values) question for more details.