# How can I set that a Spring Data JPA query method have to be a parameter value always set as true?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am not so into Hibernate and Spring Data JPA and I have the following doubt.

I have this method signature that correctly perform a query:

```
@Repository
public interface AccomodationMediaDAO extends JpaRepository<AccomodationMedia, Long> {

    AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(Long accomodationId, boolean isMaster);

}
```

It finds (on the table mapped by the **AccomodationMedia** entity class) a single record having the field named **idAccomodation** setted with the **Long** value represented by the **accomodationId** method parameter and the field **isMaster** reppresented by the **isMaster** boolean.

It works fine but my "problem" is that doing in this way I have always to explicitly pass the value of the **boolean isMaster** parameter.

This parameter has to be always set as `true`, so I tried to change the previous method signature in this way:

```
AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(Long accomodationId, true);
```

but IntelliJ displays an error: **Identifier or type expected**.

Why? Can I set that the value of this parameter have to be explicitly set to the **true** boolean value?

Comment: Because that isn't Java syntax.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As described in the [reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_query_keywords) you can just use the `IsTrue` keyword:

```
AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMasterIsTrue(Long accomodationId);
```

Comment: I think that it is the neater solution, tnx :-)

Comment: Ah nice, I kinda missed that this was a jpa question

Comment: That should work on all Spring Data repositories, not JPA only.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using Java 8, you can overload it with a `default` implementation:

```
public interface AccomodationMediaDAO extends JpaRepository<AccomodationMedia, Long> {

    AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(Long accomodationId, boolean isMaster);

    default AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(Long accomodationId) {
       return findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(accomodationId, true);
    }
}
```

But you can't provide a default value to a method parameter. E.g. see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values).

Answer (score 0):

There's no way you can set a default value into a method signature definition, you **must** tell Spring which is your parameter value explicitly. You could use a different approach in this case if you want to avoid setting your "isMaster" to true in your repository implementation. You could use the `@Query` annotation to define your own HQL query and provide the default value in you query String, this approach can be used whenever you want to create your own custom respository method using a named query instead of the named method definitions provided by Spring Data architecture.

In your particular case you can try something like this:

```
@Repository
public interface AccomodationMediaDAO extends JpaRepository<AccomodationMedia, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT a FROM AccomodationMedia a WHERE a.accomodationId = :accomodationId AND a.isMaster = true")
    AccomodationMedia findByIdAccomodationAndIsMaster(@Param(value = "accomodationId") Long accomodationId);

}
```

Please note that the properties mapped after the dot notation (a.accomodationId) name must match the entity local column names declared into your entity POJO, meaning that "accomodationId" must match the name of the variable that represents your ID column, same as applies for the "isMaster" property.