# Overriding trait method with default parameter

Tags: scala

Assume the following example - when executed returns - "fatherfather"

```
trait Action {
    def doSomething(s:String = "father") = s
}

class RevokeAction extends Action{
    override def doSomething(s:String) = {
        s + s
    }
}

object HelloWorld {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val revokeAction = new RevokeAction()
    revokeAction.doSomething()
  }
}
```

Looking at what the compiler does - gives a better explanation of what is going on

```
package <empty> {
  abstract trait Action extends Object {
    def doSomething(s: String): String = s;
    <synthetic> def doSomething$default$1(): String = "father";
    def /*Action*/$init$(): Unit = {
      ()
    }
  };
  class RevokeAction extends Object with Action {
    <synthetic> def doSomething$default$1(): String = RevokeAction.super.doSomething$default$1();
    override def doSomething(s: String): String = s.+(s);
    def <init>(): RevokeAction = {
      RevokeAction.super.<init>();
      RevokeAction.super./*Action*/$init$();
      ()
    }
  };
  object HelloWorld extends Object {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val revokeAction: RevokeAction = new RevokeAction();
      {
        revokeAction.doSomething(revokeAction.doSomething$default$1());
        ()
      }
    };
    def <init>(): HelloWorld.type = {
      HelloWorld.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Can please elaborate why this is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because that is how the Scala specification says it should work. [Section 5.1.4 (Overriding)](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/05-classes-and-objects.html#overriding):

> An overriding method **inherits all default arguments from the
>   definition in the superclass.** By specifying default arguments in the
>   overriding method it is possible to add new defaults (if the
>   corresponding parameter in the superclass does not have a default) or
>   to override the defaults of the superclass (otherwise).

Internally, Scala implementation which directs the JVM has to store the default parameter as a member of the declaring class, since the JVM [doesn't directly support default arguments on methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values).

Comment: Overlooked that statement in the spec - Thanks!

Comment: "as a constant member of the declaring class" I think you mean method.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov By "declaring class" I mean the class in which the method with the default parameter was declared.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I meant instead of "constant", not "class".

Answer (score 0):

In **Scala**, the default parameter, will create a default field to keep this value, and when you call the method without parameter, the compiler will auto set the **default parameter** as this method's parameter. like:

```
revokeAction.doSomething(revokeAction.doSomething$default$1());
```

As your decompile code, The default parameter is setted by in class `Action`:

```
<synthetic> def doSomething$default$1(): String = "father";
```

and when you call `doSomething` method without `parameter s`, it's calling:

```
revokeAction.doSomething(revokeAction.doSomething$default$1());
```

with the **default parameter**: `revokeAction.doSomething$default$1()`, since `RevokeAction`  not `override` `def doSomething$default$1()`, so default parameter is still `father`:

```
<synthetic> def doSomething$default$1(): String = RevokeAction.super.doSomething$default$1();
```