# Is it possible for Java to create a method overloading with default arguments like Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin, default-arguments

I have method with 10+ parameters actually I should write it with builder pattern. However, I think it will be a mess when converted to Kotlin. I wonder if there is a way to write java that could easily act like Kotlin does?

When we created fun with Kotlin like this

```
fun foo(bar: Int = 0, baz: Int) { /* ... */ }

foo(baz = 1) // The default value bar = 0 is used
```

How can we write similar method in java without written every possible?

E.g.

don't need to write

```
void foo(int bar, int baz){
...
}

void foo(int baz){
int bar = 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a Kotlin-flavoured version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/997482/3195526)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not really closest thing you have is something like this

```
void foo(int bar, int baz){
  ...
}

void foo(int baz){
    foo(0,baz);
}
```

Comment: Nice answer but what if you have 10+ params. That's gonna be so many methods.

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that if you look into decompiled kotlin code, you will see exactly this as (imo) is how kotlin handles default parameters in bytecode.

Comment: @umitems IMO if you have that many params you should try to refactor the method

Comment: @MarošŠeleng Kotlin does not generate code like this. It generates a normal method with all the params and a second one only for Kotlin to use with all the params and a int at the end and basing on the int it uses default params or the supplied ones

Comment: I think the difference comes from the language type java is static type and kotlin is dinmaic type that's the reason you cannot do this in java here is a link about this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages

Comment: @urag Kotlin *is* statically typed with the only exception being when compiling to JavaScript - then you have a `dynamic` type (it's still statically typed, this is used when e.g. you don't know what type the variable will be)

Comment: @MarošŠeleng I've decompiled a Kotlin function in the question and got [this code](https://pastebin.com/7PCE7HKU)

Comment: @umitems a method with 10 parameters needs to be refactored. General practice suggests that your method should require no more than 4 parameters. While this is not a hard rule, a method with too many parameters is very  unwieldy.

Comment: @jjones As I mentioned that it will be better to written on builder pattern if I written in java. Its the builder for custom dialog.