# Sending default boolean value into a method in Java

Tags: java

I want to make a method as follows:

```
private static String methodName(String name, boolean failOnMissing = true) {
    ...
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ',' Expected

Comment: Thats not going to work in Java

Comment: are you coming from c++?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values

Comment: No. You A) want to turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here, and B) you want to do that prior research thing. Dont assume that a language should have a feature (because you prefer it to be that way). Rather turn to the books and look what exactly the language has to offer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The are no default values for method arguments in Java. You can use method overloading instead.

```
private static String methodName(String name) {
    return methodName(name,true);
}

private static String methodName(String name, boolean failOnMissing) {
    ...
}
```