# Are default parameter values supported by Java?

Tags: java, methods, parameters, overloading, default-value

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values)

Suppose I want to make default parameter value in C++, then we can express it as below.

```
void functionName(char *param1, int param2=2);
```

But if I want to make this in Java, then is it possible. Currently I am doing as below

```
public functionName(String param1)
{
    this(param1, 2);
}

public functionName(String param1, int param2)
{
..........
}
```

Comment: The right column when you answer a question suggest possible duplicates. Please check it before posting.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is not possible in `Java`,but we can use the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), which is said  [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222214/managing-constructors-with-many-parameters-in-java-1-4/222295#222295).

As described in the answer reference, the Builder Pattern lets you write code like

```
Student s1 = new StudentBuilder().name("Eli").buildStudent();
Student s2 = new StudentBuilder()
                 .name("Spicoli")
                 .age(16)
                 .motto("Aloha, Mr Hand")
                 .buildStudent();
```

in which some fields can have default values or otherwise be optional.

Answer (score 5):

No. This feature is not supported in Java.

[Does Java support default parameter values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/997482/does-java-support-default-parameter-values)